# Vuetify Email Rules hangs the web page when we type very long emails?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using the

[VuetifyJs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms)
 
form component for VueJS and I'm trying to add validation to the email when you input.

But when we type very long emails, it makes the web page unresponsive and freezes the email field. I can understand that very long emails are not valid and should be avoided but then it should not hang the page.

I am using the below email rule provided by on the form component page :

```
emailRules: [
  v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
  v => /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E- 
  mail must be valid'
]
```

You can reproduce the issue on the below CodePen URL. Please do not copy paste the email. You reproduce the issue only when you type it manually.

**CodePen Url :**    https://codepen.io/dhnsh/pen/rKQpGb

**Example Email Input :** testnewlongemail@veryverylongemail.com

---

1) How can we validate the email in vuetify if its valid or not when you type ?

2) Is this a bug in the framework or something to do with the javascript behaviour ?

Comment: That regular expression is extremely inefficient, and it will reject valid email addresses anyway.

Comment: The consensus on the only valid way to validate an email address is to send a validation email to the address.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and I can understand that the rule is not correct provided on the Vuetify documentation. But still I find it very strange that it makes the complete web page unresponsive and unable to understand why ?

Comment: @DhaneshAgrawal the problem is with the way the `+` and `*` quantifiers interact. The regular expression engine has to try thousands and thousands of alternatives in order to determine whether the string matches.

Comment: [Here is a helpful link somebody posted in a related question yesterday.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: And I logged a documentation bug at the vuetify site. They should fix that.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks for the link. Is there already a regular expression that works fine for the emails instead of me creating it from the scratch ?

Comment: Personally I think that checking for `[^@]+@[^.]+\..*` is good enough to make sure you've got something that at least vaguely looks like an email address. The actual syntax is amazingly complicated. It's very, very annoying as a customer when a site disallows what one knows to be a working email address.

Comment: Oh and note that even my sample regex above will disallow some rarely-used patterns.

Comment: Yes, it gives a very bad reputation if we disallow a working email address but I also want to avoid spams as mush as possible for security reasons.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, it work for me:

```
emailRules: [
   (v) => !!v || "Email is required",
   (v) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || "Email must be valid",
]
```